# dropdownlist Select from SQL database

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I'm trying to do a project for car maintenance, and I have a small problem. The project is something like:

4 kind of maintenance plans for different cars.

```
 CarA ( MirrorA, etc etc )
 CarB ( MirrorB, etc etc )
 CarC ( MirrorC, etc etc )
 CarD ( MirrorD, etc etc )
```

What I'm trying to do is when I chose a `Car` (from a `DropDownList`), the program selects the right maintenance plan for the car!

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Select id, description from accauto_maps", con);
con.Open();
DropDownList1.DataSource = cmd.ExecuteReader();
DropDownList1.DataTextField = "description";
DropDownList1.DataValueField = "id";
DropDownList1.DataBind();
```

Now I'm stuck.

Comment: Do you have autopostback set to true ? Is this all the code that you have or is there more ?

Comment: Seeing a DropDownList and a SqlCommand in the same code block makes my eyes hurt.

Comment: Can you elaborate, what is your small problem? and where exactly you're stuck?

Comment: i´m learning by my self its not that easy -.- !! the dropdownlist is working, but i dont know how to select the the plan. the autopostback is now set to true

Answer (score 0, accepted):

now you need to set SelectedValue in this list
and/or
define event OnSelectedIndexChanged where you will process user's selection

Below the example how we did it:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlStatus" AutoPostBack="True" runat="server" DataSourceID="EDSLookStatus"
    DataValueField="cd" 
    DataTextField="lookupName" 
    OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlStatus_SelectedIndexChanged" />
<asp:TextBox ID="txtBxStatus" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("status") %>' Visible="False" />
```

Here is the trick: added invisible textbox, which is linked to "status". When ddl change value it set new value to this txtBx:

```
protected void ddlStatus_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DropDownList ddl = FormViewClient.FindControl("ddlStatus") as DropDownList;
    TextBox txtBx = FormViewClient.FindControl("txtBxStatus") as TextBox;
    if (ddl != null && txtBx != null)
    { txtBx.Text = ddl.SelectedValue; }
}
```

to set selected value:

```
<asp:FormView ... OnDataBound="FormViewClient_DataBound" >
```

and

```
protected void FormViewClient_DataBound(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ...
    DropDownList ddl = FormViewClient.FindControl("ddlStatus") as DropDownList;
    TextBox txtBx = FormViewClient.FindControl("txtBxStatus") as TextBox;
    if (ddl != null && txtBx != null)
    { ddl.SelectedValue = txtBx.Text; }
    ...
}
```

Comment: I know i have to do it i just dont know how to do it -.- Can you explain better? tks for answers i know im not good as u guys but its a answer -.- ty

Comment: i made a OnSelectedIndexChanged but i onlu can use 1 tabel...but i have 2 tabels i need to tabel A with (id"primary key", description) with a relation with tabel B (line"primary key", Map, Tip, Employer), now what i need to do is that when i chose tabel A "description" it shows me Map, Tip, Employer. the relation is betwen (tabel A id, and tabel B Map)